# Web form application, Entity framework 6.1, Build Action and web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have few question about entity framework. 
I am making an aplication in asp.net using Visual Studio 2013.
All works fine, now i try to add shop section with DB.
I made SQL db in SQL server management and using entity framework put it in to my solution.

Everything goes fine, I have my database, but it makes me few errors and questions:

1. When i try to open application in browser i've got an error which telling me that there is problem with .edmx files in web.config. I make it work adding:

   ```
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">

   <assemblies>

   <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

   <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

   </assemblies>

   </compilation>
   ```

   Insted of:

   ```
   <compilation debug="true" />
   ```

   Application starts properly.
   My question is: Is that have something in common with seccond question, or it just standard option?
2. I notice, that all files which were added by entity framework has Build Action set to: content

   Is it normal? Or should i change all to compile? For now i was forced to change files with tables name to compile, because when i'm writhing Modules code to operate this DB, (when entity talbes files got Build Action: Content) i can't use those clases.
   So my question is: Should i change every entity file Build Action to Compile, or i just need those 3 files with Table names to be changed?

**Information that may be required:**

Software: Visual Studio 2013

Framework: Entity Frmework 6.1

I made App_Code folder for my own and add ADO.NET entity data item there.
I made other folder in App_Code for c# classes. If i create class here, it also got Build Action: Content, so i must change it manualy to Compile.

Comment: Thanks about https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545940/842935 improvement. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will try to find the answer:
It is strongly NOT recommended to create app_code folder, and put there entity framework files. In other folders files are allready have compile build action.

I didn't check answer for first question, but probably this will solve both.