# Blazor Textfield Oninput User Typing Delay

Tags: c#, throttling, blazor, blazor-server-side, debouncing

How can I add a delay to an event (OnInput) in Blazor ?
For example, if a user is typing in the text field and you want to wait until the user has finished typing.
Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview8.19405.7

Code:

```
@page "/"
<input type="text" @bind="Data" @oninput="OnInputHandler"/>
<p>@Data</p>

@code {    
    public string Data { get; set; }   

    public void OnInputHandler(UIChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Data = e.Value.ToString();
    }    
}
```

Comment: just looking about debounce and throtling, I found this: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jul/02/debouncing-and-throttling-dispatcher-events

Answer (score 51, accepted):

#### Solution:

There is no single solution to your question. The following code is just one approach. Take a look and adapt it to your requirements. The code resets a timer on each `keyup`, only last timer raises the `OnUserFinish` event.
Remember to dispose timer by implementing `IDisposable`

```
@using System.Timers;
@implements IDisposable;

<input type="text" @bind="Data" @bind:event="oninput" 
       @onkeyup="@ResetTimer"/>
<p >UI Data: @Data
<br>Backend Data: @DataFromBackend</p>

@code {
    public string Data { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string DataFromBackend { get; set; }  = string.Empty;
    private Timer aTimer = default!;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        aTimer = new Timer(1000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnUserFinish;
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
    }
    void ResetTimer(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
        aTimer.Start();        
    }    
    private async void OnUserFinish(Object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415703/842935
        // Call backend
        DataFromBackend = await Task.FromResult( Data + " from backend");
        await InvokeAsync( StateHasChanged );
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
        =>
        aTimer?.Dispose();    
}
```

#### Use case:

One example of use case of this code is avoiding backend requests, because the request is not sent until user stops typing.

#### Running:

[image: sample code running]

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer and solution!
This is exactly what I was looking for and I thought I'd have to add Javascript :P As a hint yet, this source code works when you add the `@using System.Timers;`

Comment: Make sure to dispose the timer on the Dispose method of the component

Comment: @Alexandre wow, thanks about your advice. Are you so kind to improve te answer? Be free to edit it.

Comment: Awesome solution, have been looking for this me too. Thanks @dani

Answer (score 12):

This answer is the middle ground between the previous answers, i.e. between [DIY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545940/1025555) and [using a full-blown reactive UI framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64041336/1025555).

It utilizes the powerful [Reactive.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive) library (a.k.a. *Rx*), which in my opinion is the only reasonable way to solve such problems in normal scenarios.

## The solution

After installing the NuGet package [`System.Reactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive) you can import the needed namespaces in your component:

```cs
@using System.Reactive.Subjects
@using System.Reactive.Linq
```

Create a `Subject` field on your component that will act as the glue between the input event and your `Observable` pipeline:

```cs
@code {
    private Subject<ChangeEventArgs> searchTerm = new();
    // ...
}
```

Connect the `Subject` with your `input`:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" @oninput=@searchTerm.OnNext>
```

Finally, define the `Observable` pipeline:

```cs
@code {
    // ...

    private Thing[]? things;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        searchTerm
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            .Select(e => (string?)e.Value)
            .Select(v => v?.Trim())
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .SelectMany(SearchThings)
            .Subscribe(ts => {
                things = ts;
                StateHasChanged();
            });
    }

    private Task<Thing[]> SearchThings(string? searchTerm = null)
        => HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Thing[]>($"api/things?search={searchTerm}")
}
```

The example pipeline above will...

- give the user 200 milliseconds to finish typing (a.k.a. *debouncing* or *throttling* the input),
- select the typed value from the `ChangeEventArgs`,
- trim it,
- skip any value that is the same as the last one,
- use all values that got this far to issue an HTTP GET request,
- store the response data on the field `things`,
- and finally tell the component that it needs to be re-rendered.

If you have something like the below in your markup, you will see it being updated when you type:

```cs
@foreach (var thing in things) {
    <ThingDisplay Item=@thing @key=@thing.Id />
}
```

## Additional notes

### Don't forget to clean up

You should properly dispose the event subscription like so:

```cs
@implements IDisposable // top of your component

// markup

@code {
    // ...

    private IDisposable? subscription;

    public void Dispose() => subscription?.Dispose();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        subscription = searchTerm
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            // ...
            .Subscribe(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

`Subscribe()` actually returns an `IDisposable` that you should store and dispose along with your component. But do *not* use `using` on it, because this would destroy the subscription prematurely.

### Open questions

There are some things I haven't figured out yet:

- Is it possible to avoid calling `StateHasChanged()`?
- Is it possible to avoid calling `Subscribe()` and bind directly to the `Observable` inside the markup like you would do in Angular using the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)?
- Is it possible to avoid creating a `Subject`? Rx supports creating `Observable`s from C# `Event`s, but how do I get the C# object for the `oninput` event?

Comment: Great solution! I had to wrap the assignment and the `StateHasChanged()` into an `InvokeAsync` call, to ensure that both are executed in the right context and do not throw random exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a set of [Blazor components](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components). One of which is [Debounced inputs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/DebounceInputs.md) with multiple input types and much more features. Blazor.Components.Debounce.Input is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Debounce.Input/).

You can try it out with the [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/debounceinput).

**Note: currently it is in Preview. Final version is coming with .NET 5. release**

Comment: Any chance for a version for .NET Core 3.1 ?

Comment: @akrobet Thanks for contacting me. I'm using new CSS isolation and JS Interop features. So it is already huge effort to work on the components making it targeting multiple frameworks would be much more work. So short answer is no, sorry... You should update your App to .NET 5 soon anyway.

Comment: Yes, I might end up doing that, once the stable version is out. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes .NET 5 has some issues for now, but will be released in one month.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better solution for me, I used it for searching.
Here's the code that I used.

```
    private DateTime timer {
      get;
      set;
    } = DateTime.MinValue;


    private async Task SearchFire(ChangeEventArgs Args) {
      if (timer == DateTime.MinValue) {
        timer = DateTime.UtcNow;
      } else {
        _ = StartSearch(Args);
        timer = DateTime.UtcNow;
      }
    }

    private async Task StartSearch(ChangeEventArgs Args) { //2000 = 2 seconeds you can change it 
      await Task.Delay(2000);
      var tot = TimeSpan.FromTicks((DateTime.UtcNow - timer).Ticks).TotalSeconds;
      if (tot > 2) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Args.Value.ToString())) { //Do anything after 2 seconds.

          //reset timer after finished writhing
          timer = DateTime.MinValue;
        } else {}
      } else {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid bind the input. Just set @oninput

```
<Input id="theinput" @oninput="OnTextInput" />
@code {
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
    public void OnTextInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeField = e.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

and set initial value in javascript (if there is).

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setInitialValueById", "theinput", SomeField);
    }
}
```

The **setInitialValueById** method:

```
window.setInitialValueById = (elementId, value) => {
document.getElementById(elementId).value = value;}
```

This will resolve the known input lag issue in blazor. You can set a label value with delay if it's the case:

```
public async Task OnTextInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var value = e.Value.ToString();
    SomeField = value;
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setLabelValue", value);
}
```

The **setLabelValue** method:

```
let lastInput;
window.setLabelValue = (value) => {
    lastInput = value;
    setTimeout(() => {
        let inputValue = value;
        if (inputValue === lastInput) {
            document.getElementById("theLabelId").innerHTML = inputValue;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```