# The @onkeypress doesn't get the updated value of Text input box?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following code.

```
<input id="search" type="text" @bind="Search" @onkeypress="SearchChanged" />
@code {
    string Search;

    void SearchChanged() 
    { 
        var s = Search; // Search is always one character behind
    }
}
```

Typing in the text box will trigger the function `SearchChanged`. However, the value it got is always one character before the typed text. For example, setting a break point in `SearchChanged`,

```
Typed Value of  Search
===== ================
a     null
ab    a
abc   ab
abcd  abc
```

BTW, the `@onkeypress` doesn't work in Internet Browser?

---

Tried to change the code to

```
<input id="search" type="text" @bind="Search" />
@code {
    string search;
    string Search 
    {
        get { return search; }
        set {
            search = value;
            ResultList = GetNewList(search).Result.ToList(); 
        }
    }

    void SearchChanged() 
    { 
        var s = Search; // Search is always one character behind
    }
}
```

I set a break point in the `set {  }`, however, the break point is hit just one or two times when typing the text box?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `@bind-value:event`:

```
<input id="search" 
       type="text" 
       @bind-value="Search" 
       @bind-value:event="oninput"
/>

@code {
  string search;
  string Search 
  {
    get { return search; }
    set {
        search = value;
        ResultList = GetNewList(search).Result.ToList(); 
      }
  }
```

Quoting [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#data-binding) docs:

> In addition to handling onchange events with @bind syntax, a property or field can be bound using other events by specifying an @bind-value attribute with an event parameter (@bind-value:event).

Comment: I want to use Rx to throttle the key press so less database calls will be invoked. Is there a way to to create IObservable on the events for Blazor?

Comment: This is a new question. But I already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545940/842935