# How can i add a delay oninput event in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

How can I add a delay to an event (OnInput) in Blazor ?
For example, if a user is typing in the text field and you want to wait until the user has finished typing

Code:

```
<p>Filter value: @filterQuery</p>
    <input  value="@filterQuery"@oninput="TextChanged"/>
    public async void TextChanged(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs)
    {

        string searchText = changeEventArgs.Value.ToString();
        filterQuery = searchText;
{Do stuff....}

    }
```

To be clear I want the [do stuff] portion to be executed not everytime the user types something, but lets say after a second delay where there are no longer typing events

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533970/blazor-textfield-oninput-user-typing-delay has the answer

Comment: Watch from this moment about SearchBounced https://youtu.be/MetcuX1OHD0?t=1024