# C# / Blazor How to apply filter after get data from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have a class/entity over a project.

Entity example:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In Blazor file I have this code below.
projList get data from my repository,
filterList = projList works

```
@code {
    private IEnumerable<Project> projList { get; set; } = new List<Project>();
    private List<Project> filterList { get; set; } = new List<Project>();

    public string projFilter { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    ..
    
    private async Task ApplyProjFilter()
    {
        ..
        filterList = projList.Where(p => p.ProjectId.Contains(projFilter)).ToList();
        ..
    }
```

I get an error on the above instruction with .Contains.
I can use

```
(p => p.ProjectId == projFilter).ToList()
```

but I want to filter my list on the run when the user writes a filter in the textbox and show the projects that contain that input string.

.Contains works if I use it in my repository when I read data from the server but I will not use it on the run because it will cause a lot of questions to SQL-server.

Any idéa what is wrong?

I'm using the latest netcore and efcore and Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: So you want to show any projects where the `ProjectId` string contains the substring `projFilter`?  Or starts with?

Answer (score 0):

I post a code snipped based on your question, be free to change it to match your requirements:

```
<input type="text" @oninput="@( (e) => ApplyProjFilter(e) )">
<li>
@foreach(var p in filterList)
{
    <li>@p.Name</li>
}
</li>

@code {
    public class Project
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Project> projList { get; set; } 
    private List<Project> filterList { get; set; } 
    public string projFilter { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        projList = new []
        {
            new Project{ Name = "pA"},
            new Project{ Name = "pB"} //, ...
        }.ToList();
        filterList = projList.ToList();
    }

    private async Task ApplyProjFilter(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        projFilter = e.Value.ToString();
        filterList = projList.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(projFilter)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Check it out running at: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QPOGluvA27eghIPO51

#### Debounce:

Reading *"it will cause a lot of questions to SQL-server"* I think, maybe, you are looking for `debounce`

In some cases it is not a good idea to get all remote data to the client side (if you have more than 300 o 400 records this request can kill performance)

Take a look to this answer to learn about debounce on blazor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57545940/842935

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still got the same error : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

DataAccess.Data.Project.ProjectId.get returned null.

Comment: Could it be that I have an public virtual ICollection<ProjData> ProjDatas { get; set; } ?  in my Class Project?

Comment: In your code `ProjectId` is nullable. Before compare check it is not null: `...ProjectId != null && ...`